# Как правильно остановить поток, который использует критическую секцию?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, synchronized

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно остановить поток, который использует `CriticalSection`, в C++ используя WinAPI. Функция потока у меня выглядит примерно так:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadFunc(LPVOID param) {
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    ...
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
    return 0;
}
```

И в любой момент времени, во время действия потоков, я останавливаю любой из `n` потоков при помощи функции `TerminateThread`, которая не освобождает `CriticalSection` из-за чего, когда очередь доходит до этого потока, то на строчке `LeaveCriticalSection` возникает вот такая ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x76EBF463 (ntdll.dll) в MultiThreadApp.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x0528F948.

Так как правильно остановить поток, который использует критическую секцию?

**EDIT:**

Решил попробовать использовать оболочку для `CRITICAL_SECTION`, вот пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

const int THREADS_COUNT = 10;
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
HANDLE threads[THREADS_COUNT];
clock_t start;

class LockCriticalSection {
public:
    LockCriticalSection(CRITICAL_SECTION* cs) : cs(cs) { }
    void Lock() { EnterCriticalSection(cs); }
    ~LockCriticalSection() { LeaveCriticalSection(cs); }
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION* cs;
};

DWORD WINAPI threadFunc(LPVOID param) {
    LockCriticalSection test(&cs);
    test.Lock();

    printf("THREAD - %d before sleep\n", (int)param);
    Sleep(2000);
    printf("THREAD - %d after sleep\n", (int)param);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; ++i)
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadFunc, (LPVOID)i, 0, NULL);

    Sleep(2000);

    printf("Terminate Thread\n");
    TerminateThread(threads[4], 0);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADS_COUNT, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);

    clock_t end = clock() - start;

    char resultTime[128];
    sprintf_s(resultTime, "Время выполнения программы: %f", end / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("%s", resultTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; ++i)
        CloseHandle(threads[i]);

    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
    return 0;
}
```

Но он так же возвращает ошибку при `LeaveCriticalSection`

Answer (score 1):

Правильный способ остановки потока только один - дождаться завершения его работы и закрыть дескриптор. `TerminateThread` использовать категорически нельзя.

Comment: Можно поставить на паузу и забыть о потоке. Правда и в секцию лучше тогда больше не заходить...

Comment: Я понимаю это, но мне нужно остановить поток самому, не дожидаясь его окончания.

Comment: @Bonifacy А так не получится. Собственно возникновение такой необходимости говорит о том, что делается что-то не то.

Comment: Если нужно именно остановить потом, а не сделать ему харакири, то используется булевая переменная, которую поток время от времени проверяет и, при необходимости, сам завершается.